# Save a xlsx file with PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I want to create an xlsx file and I'm using PHPExcel. For now I just added a line and I'm trying to create and save the file but it doesn't work.

My code is :

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $chemin = "./././files/resultats/simulation".$singleton->getNom()."_".date("d").".".date("m").".".date("y").".xml";
    $xmlFile = simplexml_load_file($chemin);

    $ligne = "3";
    $colonne = "B";

    foreach ($xmlFile as $xml) //on aprcours les attributs <Simulation>
    {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Synthèse système culture');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("B".$ligne,"Nom du système de culture");
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells("B3:B4");

        $ligne++; //Quand on termine une simulation, on ajoute une ligne pour afficher la simulation suivante sur la ligne du dessous
    }
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="test.xlsx"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save('test.xlsx');
```

What is wrong with that ? I'm trying to save "test.xlsx" and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You are saving the .xlsx file to the server and not to the output stream. You could do this by using:

```
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Or by reading the saved file to the output buffer using:

```
readfile('test.xlsx');
```